# sql select a record containing a phrase

Tags: sql

I want to query a record containing a phrase.

for example: I want the search to return the record: 'The needle in the haystack' with the search phrase 'needle haystack'

The query will work if I just have 'needle' or just 'haystack' using like% in the where clause.

Is there a way to search with the phrase 'needle haystack'?

Comment: `%needle%haystack%` should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE phrase LIKE '%needle%' AND phrase LIKE '%haystack%'
```

Replace `phrase` with `LOWER(phrase)` if you want the search to be case-insensitive (depends on the DB engine and other things, though).

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this

```
select * from Suppliers where patindex(REPLACE('%' + 'YOUR SEARCH STRING' + '%',' ','%'),CompanyName) > 1
```